# Function App uses other outbound IP-addresses than MS docs say

Tags: azure, azure-functions

One of my Azure Function App functions upload files via FTP. The destination FW blocks all IPs by default. We therefore added all IP-addresses of the "North Europe" datacenter as per [instructions from Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses), since we run Consumption Plan.

I also logged all outbound IP-addresses from within the function that uploads via FTP and found that the actual used IP-addresses not always match those inside [Azure IP Ranges for Data Centers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). The IPs logged were:

```
40.67.229.13
52.158.47.186 <-- matches 52.158.0.0/17 (right?)
40.67.241.77 
52.158.34.236 <-- matches 52.158.0.0/17
40.67.225.58
52.158.33.63 <-- matches 52.158.0.0/17
40.67.225.164 
52.158.33.107 <-- matches 52.158.0.0/17
13.74.242.151 <-- matches 13.74.0.0/16
13.79.113.64 <-- matches 13.79.0.0/16
13.74.240.205 <-- matches 13.74.0.0/16
13.79.113.75 <-- matches 13.79.0.0/16
```

While the IPs of North Europe is

```
13.69.128.0/17
13.70.192.0/18
13.74.0.0/16
13.79.0.0/16
13.94.64.0/18
13.104.148.0/25
13.104.149.128/25
13.104.150.0/25
13.104.208.160/28
13.104.210.0/24
13.105.18.0/26
13.105.21.0/24
13.105.37.192/26
20.38.64.0/19
20.38.102.0/23
20.47.8.0/24
20.47.20.0/23
20.47.32.0/24
20.47.111.0/24
20.47.117.0/24
20.50.64.0/20
20.54.0.0/17
20.150.26.0/24
20.150.47.128/25
20.150.48.0/24
20.150.75.0/24
20.150.84.0/24
20.190.129.0/24
20.190.159.0/24
20.191.0.0/18
23.100.48.0/20
23.100.128.0/18
23.101.48.0/20
23.102.0.0/18
40.67.224.0/19
40.69.0.0/18
40.69.64.0/19
40.69.192.0/19
40.77.133.0/24
40.77.136.32/28
40.77.136.80/28
40.77.165.0/24
40.77.174.0/24
40.77.175.160/27
40.77.182.96/27
40.77.226.128/25
40.77.229.0/24
40.77.234.160/27
40.77.236.0/27
40.77.236.176/28
40.77.255.0/25
40.78.211.0/24
40.85.0.0/17
40.85.128.0/20
40.87.128.0/19
40.87.188.0/22
40.90.17.192/27
40.90.25.64/26
40.90.25.128/26
40.90.31.128/25
40.90.129.192/27
40.90.130.224/28
40.90.133.64/27
40.90.136.176/28
40.90.137.192/27
40.90.140.64/27
40.90.141.96/27
40.90.141.128/27
40.90.145.0/27
40.90.145.224/27
40.90.147.96/27
40.90.148.160/28
40.90.149.128/25
40.90.153.128/25
40.91.20.0/22
40.91.32.0/22
40.112.36.0/25
40.112.37.64/26
40.112.64.0/19
40.113.0.0/18
40.113.64.0/19
40.115.96.0/19
40.126.1.0/24
40.126.31.0/24
40.127.96.0/20
40.127.128.0/17
51.104.64.0/18
51.104.128.0/18
52.108.174.0/23
52.108.176.0/24
52.108.196.0/24
52.108.240.0/21
52.109.76.0/22
52.111.236.0/24
52.112.232.0/24
52.112.236.0/24
52.113.40.0/21
52.113.48.0/20
52.113.112.0/20
52.113.136.0/21
52.113.205.0/24
52.114.76.0/22
52.114.96.0/21
52.114.120.0/22
52.114.231.0/24
52.114.233.0/24
52.114.248.0/22
52.115.16.0/21
52.115.24.0/22
52.120.136.0/21
52.120.192.0/20
52.121.16.0/21
52.121.48.0/20
52.125.138.0/23
52.138.128.0/17
52.142.64.0/18
52.143.195.0/24
52.143.209.0/24
52.146.128.0/17
52.155.64.0/19
52.155.128.0/17
52.156.192.0/18
52.158.0.0/17
52.164.0.0/16
52.169.0.0/16
52.178.128.0/17
52.232.148.0/24
52.236.0.0/17
52.239.136.0/22
52.239.205.0/24
52.239.248.0/24
52.245.40.0/22
52.245.88.0/22
65.52.64.0/20
65.52.224.0/21
94.245.88.0/21
94.245.104.0/21
94.245.114.1/32
94.245.114.2/31
94.245.114.4/32
94.245.114.33/32
94.245.114.34/31
94.245.114.36/32
94.245.117.96/27
94.245.118.0/27
94.245.118.65/32
94.245.118.66/31
94.245.118.68/32
94.245.118.97/32
94.245.118.98/31
94.245.118.100/32
94.245.118.129/32
94.245.118.130/31
94.245.118.132/32
94.245.120.128/28
94.245.122.0/24
94.245.123.144/28
94.245.123.176/28
104.41.64.0/18
104.41.192.0/18
104.44.88.64/27
104.44.91.64/27
104.44.92.192/27
104.44.94.32/28
104.45.80.0/20
104.45.96.0/19
104.46.8.0/21
104.46.64.0/19
104.47.218.0/23
131.253.40.80/28
134.170.80.64/28
137.116.224.0/19
137.135.128.0/17
138.91.48.0/20
157.55.3.0/24
157.55.10.160/29
157.55.10.176/28
157.55.13.128/26
157.55.107.0/24
157.55.204.128/25
157.55.230.161/32
157.55.230.162/31
157.55.230.164/32
168.61.80.0/20
168.61.96.0/19
168.63.32.0/19
168.63.64.0/20
168.63.80.0/21
168.63.92.0/22
191.232.138.0/23
191.235.128.0/18
191.235.192.0/22
191.235.208.0/20
191.235.255.0/24
191.237.192.0/23
191.237.194.0/24
191.237.196.0/24
191.237.208.0/20
191.238.96.0/19
191.239.208.0/20
193.149.88.0/21
```

What's going on here? What is it that I don't understand? It seems to me that the Azure IP-ranges json is missing 40.67.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `40.67.224.0/19` range matches - the last number in the CIDR notation is the number of significant bits, which in this case means all 16 bits of `40.67` plus the first 3 bits of `224`, which is `11100000` in binary. So it matches addresses from `40.67.224.0` to `40.67.255.255`, which includes the four addresses in your output.

Comment: Ah. I regret not having paid more attention 25 years back when we ran LAN parties. But alas, I can still learn :-)